# Accessing Sqflite in Android specific code

Tags: android, database, flutter, sqflite

I have SQLite database implemented in flutter with Sqflite plugin.

I would like to access this database in Android platform-specific code in Kotlin. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The database created in flutter is saved at the following path:

```
/data/data/{package name}/app_flutter/{database file name}
```

The database can be easily accessed with:

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/{package name}/app_flutter/{database file name}", null, 0)
```